# How to run tests in behat on firefox 48.0 using selenium stand alone server?

Tags: selenium, firefox, phpstorm, behat

Previously I worked with Behat 3 and Stand Alone Server 2.45 and everything worked properly.

I use PhpStorm as my IDE. Later, after installing the update of Firefox (ver. 48.0) my tests stop working. I also try to run tests with Selenium Standalone Server ver. 3.0.0-beta3 but Firefox browser not open.

Is there any way to run tests under browser FF 48.0? Maybe someone would like to share information about the working configuration of Behat, FF48 and Stand Alone Server?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you get any error in behat or selenium console? Possible that you may need to use geckodriver. I suggest to use chrome, for me alt least is slightly faster and more reliable. For chrome you also need to start selenium with chrome driver.

Comment: Could You show me command to run selenium stand alone server with chromedriver?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your behat.yml?

Answer (score 6):

Starting the selenium server standalone with chrome driver command,

for latest selenium (3.0+)

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar
```

for older versions (lower than 3)

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe
```

So for the latest selenium you need to specify the driver first and after that, the selenium jar.

> Note: use the appropriate chromedriver version for your os

Comment: I was run server like You do:  $ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar /home/grzegorz/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar But I get this error: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnqpisr4rs8oueo/paragraf%20-%20%5B~-PhpstormProjects-paragraf%5D%20-%20...-behat.yml%20-%20PhpStorm%202016.1.21601.png?dl=0] I'm working on kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Try the latest version of chromedriver, after that try with an older version too.Also check that you don't have any custom code in FeatureContext that could affect this, like creating a new session or something like that.

Comment: Start selenium and see if any error occurs, run test and see any error occurs. Post errors(full stack trace) if any and post any custom code from FeatureContext that might affect this.

Comment: Ok. First try '$ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver224 -jar /home/grzegorz/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar'. Errors after run the test. Console [part 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ql8he2fx9e44sw9/console%20error%20part%201.png?dl=0), [part 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ez8ao346l8evygc/console%20error%20part%202.png?dl=0), [part 3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kw84rdugx2158rf/console%20error%20part%203.png?dl=0). [PhpStorm error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qa27ufeclsk9acw/phpstorm%20error%20part%201.png?dl=0).

Comment: [My FeatureContext file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lz6npwtgscvh1zf/FeatureContext%20file.png?dl=0). I'm not creating new session anywhere in this file.

Comment: Second try. `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/home/grzegorz/chromedriver223 -jar /home/grzegorz//selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar I also get errors: [part 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xanwtn9g8e08g4u/1.png?dl=0), [part 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/osgbeie3gtumiis/2.png?dl=0), [part 3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdavsrbfzcwsz6q/3.png?dl=0) [Phpstorm error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0awxctho6ca9wan/4.png?dl=0)

Comment: I will take a look to see if I can spot any issue.Check that you have browser set to chrome in behat.yml

Comment: Configuration looks like this: [behat.yml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dun69939qx9r9ml/5.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we need some more information about your behat.yml and the information that the selenium logs are giving to you.

Only for reference, here you have my config for running firefox under Behat 3 an Selenium3-beta3.

```
    extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: "http://www.your-web.dev/"
        sessions:
            firefox_mac:
                selenium2:
                    browser: "firefox"
                    wd_host: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/wd/hub
                    capabilities: { "platform": "MAC", "browser": "firefox", "version": "" }
```

You should link your PHPStorm to the behat executable and the configuration file to the firefox behat.yml. If you have your interpreter in PhpStorm well configured, it should work.

Does Phpstorm shows you some error?

Comment: My behat.yml file:
`code`
#behat.yml
default:
 autoload:
     '': %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
 extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      files_path: /home/grzegorz/PhpstormProjects/paragraf/images
      default_session: selenium2
      base_url: http://MY_SITE.com
      selenium2:
        wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
      browser_name: 'firefox'
`code`
And I run stand alone server in console using this command: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar

Comment: And when I run test from PHPStorm I have this error: Could not open connection: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Comment: Try to change this:
wd_host: "127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"; 
browser_name: 'firefox'
For this:
browser: "firefox"
wd_host: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/wd/hub
capabilities: { "platform": "MAC", "browser": "firefox", "version": "" } Changing the platform to whatever you are using. (I know you are not in a grid mode, aren't you?)

Comment: I make changes like You suggest me. But Error remains the same. Should I add some extra lines to FutureContext.php?

Comment: Ok, I think that the problem here is that Selenium is not finding the geckodriver. After updating to a newer Firefox version than 47, the Firefox geckodriver must be passed in the selenium server command. 
So, when you start the selenium server add this: -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/path/to/geckodriver.exe

Comment: java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/path/to/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar

Comment: Nice! No problem! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Behat is not compatible at the moment with selenium3 use selenium 2.53 instead.