# Unable to run selenium tests on chrome locally on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to run chrome tests locally on Mac(El Capitan) , however i am unable to run the tests locally on chrome , i am able to invoke chrome using remote webdriver. But when i try to run the tests without the remote webdriver i.e invoking chrome directly I am getting error

```
    driver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/testuser/practise/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 92, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver
```

I have the chromedriver binary located in `/usr/local/bin` and i have the same in my **PATH** as well.

```
Selenium Version: selenium (2.53.6)
Chromedriver Version: 2.24.417412
Python Version: 2.7.10
```

MY sample script

```
# Import unittest module for creating unit tests
import unittest

# Import time module to implement
import time

# Import the Selenium 2 module (aka "webdriver")
from selenium import webdriver

# For automating data input
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# For providing custom configurations for Chrome to run
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# --------------------------------------
# Provide a class for the unit test case
class PythonOrgSearchChrome(unittest.TestCase):

    # Anything declared in setUp will be executed for all test cases
    def setUp(self):
        # Select which device you want to emulate by uncommenting it
        # More information at: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation
        mobile_emulation = {

            "deviceName": "Google Nexus 5"
            # Or specify a specific build using the following two arguments
            #"deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
            #"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
        }

        # Define a variable to hold all the configurations we want
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        # Add the mobile emulation to the chrome options variable
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

        # Create driver, pass it the path to the chromedriver file and the special configurations you want to run
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

    # An individual test case. Must start with 'test_' (as per unittest module)
    def test_search_in_python_chrome(self):
        # Assigning a local variable for the global driver
        driver = self.driver

        # Go to google.com
        driver.get('http://www.google.com')

        # A test to ensure the page has keyword Google in the page title
        self.assertIn("Google", driver.title)



        # Find and select the search box element on the page
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

        # Enter text into the search box
        search_box.send_keys('Cat gif')

        # Make sure the results page returned something
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

        # Submit the search box form
        search_box.submit()

        # Can also use Keys function to submit
        #search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        # Another pause so we can see what's going on
        time.sleep(5)

        # Take a screenshot of the results
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshot-deskto-chrome.png')

    # Anything declared in tearDown will be executed for all test cases
    def tearDown(self):
        # Close the browser.
        # Note close() will close the current tab, if its the last tab it will close the browser. To close the browser entirely use quit()
        self.driver.close()

# Boilerplate code to start the unit tests
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I am really not sure what is happening , because i am able to launch the browser using remote webdriver, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried latest selenium with latest chromedriver? To avoid any issues related to the path you could save them both(selenium and chromedriver) in the same directory and run from there. Sometimes you might have incompatibilities between chromedriver and chrome browser if the browser will auto-update.

Comment: AFAIK am running the latest versions of chromedriver and selenium. The same works fine when i invoke the chrome using remote webdriver .If it was a path problem then the remote webdriver should have complained as well

Comment: I think that the latest selenium is 3.0. Please recheck and see here my answer of how to start selenium with chromedriver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468600/how-to-run-tests-in-behat-on-firefox-48-0-using-selenium-stand-alone-server

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the answer , in my `/etc/hosts` `localhost` was mapped to something else as a result which i was getting

```
driver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/testuser/practise/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 92, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver
```