# How to setup Behat with Selenium Standalone Server and Firefox 49?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, bdd, behat

Can anyone explain in details how to setup and run [Behat](http://behat.org/en/latest/) with [Selenium Standalone Server 3.0.0-beta 4](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and Firefox 49.

Actually I have problem with setup behat.yml. I have try like it is explained [How to run tests in behat on firefox 48.0 using selenium stand alone server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468600/how-to-run-tests-in-behat-on-firefox-48-0-using-selenium-stand-alone-server) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you want to ride a grid or a basic Selenium server? The test will run in Windows, mac or ubuntu?
Have you tried as I explain in the last comment of the second answer (in the link you found)?

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/path/to/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta4.jar
```

What did you define in your behat.yml?
Hope I can help you.